# How to copy ACF fields from one page to another using php?

Tags: php, wordpress

As the question states, how do I copy an ACF field from one post to another? This is what I have so far. Any help would be appreciated.

```
add_action('save_post', 'dupe-expiration-date');

function dupe-expiration-date()
{
    // Gets expiration date from 'Homepage' page
    $date_field_data = get_field('sale_expiration_date', 2361);
    
    // Sets expration date on 'Deals' page
    update_field('sale_expiration_date', $date_field_data, 34412);
}
```

Comment: Those hyphens probably won't work as the function name. What is going wrong at the moment with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, my code works. I don't know PHP so when I created the function dupe-expiration-date, I didn't know I couldn't use the character '-' to name the function.

Once I corrected that issue, the code worked as intended.